# Changing password of a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, mount, qemu, kvm

I have some virtual machines with me. I want to write a script which automates the following process...

- It mounts the virtual machine (with linux as the os) to a location say /mnt/image
- It modifies the /etc/passwd (or the equivalent file) to change the password of the user
- Unmount the virtual machine

Since, I am using libvirt I am having some qcow2 images of the virtual machine. to mount the image on my ubuntu, I am using nbd module. Here are the commands that I am trying :

```
modprobe nbd max_part=63
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.qcow2
mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/image
```

It gives me the error:

```
mount: special device /dev/nbd0p1 does not exist
```

When I replace nbd0p1 with nbdo I am getting the following error (though I am not sure what I am trying to do by this)

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Any suggestions so as what could be the problem... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not a direct answer to the question, but an alternate]
You can try to convert qcow2 image to raw and then, mount the raw image.

convert:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 image.qcow2 -O raw image_raw.raw
```

mount:

```
    sudo losetup /dev/loop0 image_raw.raw
    sudo kpartx -a /dev/loop0
    sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p3 /mnt/image
    sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/image/boot
```

Comment: Error mount: special device /dev/mapper/loop0p3 does not exist on existing the third line

Comment: Maybe, you can try [sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/image] or [sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/image] (loop0p<i> depends on your partition)

Comment: check this link http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2008/10/mounting-kvm-disk-image.html for more information. Using [kpartx -av /dev/loop0] will output some more information about your partitions.

Comment: kpartx -av /dev/loop0 doesn't give any output. I tried the above link but i encontered exactly the same errors. I tried different p<i> but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Check that `/sys/modules/nbd/parameters/max_part` has the expected value. If it's 0 or too low, the partitions `/dev/nbd0p1`, etc. will not be made available by the kernel. This can happen if the `nbd` kernel module was already loaded (with a different `max_part` parameter) when you ran `modprobe`.

You can fix that by unloading the module and modprobing it again.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the partition isn't in the first slot in the MBR, or an extended partition is in use?  Check to see if any other `nbdXpY` device nodes are being created, or run `fdisk` on it and `p`rint the partition table.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on the same issue and same error but on a vdi

```
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.vdi
```

for me the solution was simple I just changed `nbd0` to `nbd1`

```
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 image.vdi
```

and then:

```
sudo mount  /dev/nbd1p1 /media/eddie/virtual
```

worked.

Please leave a comment if this worked for you also and on what type of image.